# Is there a way to specify variable in grunt task name?

Tags: gruntjs

Is there a way to specify variable in grunt task name?
I would like to do something like

```
 grunt build version 0.1
```

and then in gruntfile.js

```
grunt.initConfig({
    version: // read that version
 files: {
          '<%= version %>.js'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
YourTask: {
    dist: {
        files: { 'dist.<%= version %>.js', ........
    }
},
```

Register your `build` task like this:

```
grunt.task.registerTask('build', 'build a specific version', 
function(version) {
  if (arguments.length === 0) {
    grunt.log.writeln(this.name + ", missing version");
  } else {
    grunt.log.writeln(this.name + " version " + version);
    grunt.config.set('version', version);
    grunt.task.run([
       'YourTask:dist'
    ]);
  }
});
```

You would then call: `grunt build:0.1`

Comment: but i had to add iside task: 
configObj.version = version;
grunt.initConfig(configObj);

Comment: can you also help me resolve this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255572/parameters-binding-in-grunt-tasks
I am still working with  grunt

Answer (score 0):

I can hardly understand why do you need to use different names in grunt-tasks. But the thing you are talking about seems like arguments usage. Try these code:

```
grunt.registerTask('custom', 'Build version', function () {  
  grunt.config.set('ver', grunt.option('ver') || 0);
  grunt.task.run('build');
});
```

And run it with `--ver` argument:

```
grunt custom --ver=0.1
```

Comment: Actually I think @Rachid's solution is scalable.